# Jetty 9 Embedded with Security + Servlets + StaticResources

Tags: security, servlets, static, jetty

I am trying in the last few days or so to run an embedded jetty server but I can't configure my security handler like I want..

The initialization code is like this:

```
interfaceServer = new Server(configManager.getServerPort());
// Initializing the security handler
ServletContextHandler appContext = new ServletContextHandler(interfaceServer, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
// SECURITY HANDLER
ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setConstraintMappings(getConstraintMappings());
securityHandler.setLoginService(getLoginService());
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(getAuthenticator());
securityHandler.setCheckWelcomeFiles(true);
// Set security
appContext.setSecurityHandler(securityHandler);
appContext.setResourceBase(webDir);
appContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"gui.tmpl"});
// Add servlets
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SyncServlet(systemOutBypass)), "/sync");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new CommandServlet(configManager)), "/exec");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ConfigServlet(configManager)), "/conf");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new FeedServlet(configManager)), "/feed");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ProxyServlet(configManager)), "/proxy");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new BrowseServlet(configManager)), "/browse");
appContext.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");
// Apply to server
interfaceServer.setHandler(appContext);
interfaceServer.start();
```

Helper functions:

```
private static ConstraintMapping[] getConstraintMappings() {
    // CONSTRAINT
    Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
    constraint.setName(Constraint.__FORM_AUTH);
    constraint.setRoles(new String[]{"user", "admin"});
    constraint.setAuthenticate( true );
    // MAPPINGS
    ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
    mapping.setPathSpec( "*.tmpl" );
    mapping.setConstraint( constraint );

    return new ConstraintMapping[] {mapping};
}

private static LoginService getLoginService(){
    // HASH LOGIN SERVICE
    HashLoginService loginService = new HashLoginService();
    loginService.putUser("admin", new Password("admin"), new String[] {"user"});
    return loginService;
    }

private static Authenticator getAuthenticator(){
    // FORM AUTH
    return new FormAuthenticator("/login.tmpl", "/login.tmpl", false);
}
```

Configured like this it works but I am redirected to the login page only if I enter `http://127.0.0.1:8083/gui.tmpl` while `http://127.0.0.1:8083/` shows the gui.tmpl file but doesn't load all the other stuff and doesn't redirect me.. If I change the setPathSpec path to "/" security is applied to the whole app but static files aren't accessible so the login form is not styled (I am forced to style it with inline css)

The wanted behaviour is security applied only to a folder or set of files and accessible static files like css, images etc.. Is it possible? If not, the only solution is inline styling? Please help!

You can find the full project at [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/ntrp/ums_webinterface), experimental branch (check the master too in case..)

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain handlers in proper way (order). Add appContext to securityHandler, not the other way.

```
interfaceServer = new Server(configManager.getServerPort());
// Initializing the security handler
ServletContextHandler appContext = new ServletContextHandler(interfaceServer, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS | ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
// SECURITY HANDLER
ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setConstraintMappings(getConstraintMappings());
securityHandler.setLoginService(getLoginService());
securityHandler.setAuthenticator(getAuthenticator());
securityHandler.setCheckWelcomeFiles(true);
securityHandler.setHandler(appContext);
// Set security
appContext.setResourceBase(webDir);
appContext.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"gui.tmpl"});
// Add servlets
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SyncServlet(systemOutBypass)), "/sync");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new CommandServlet(configManager)), "/exec");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ConfigServlet(configManager)), "/conf");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new FeedServlet(configManager)), "/feed");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ProxyServlet(configManager)), "/proxy");
appContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new BrowseServlet(configManager)), "/browse");
appContext.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");
// Apply to server
interfaceServer.setHandler(securityHandler);
interfaceServer.start();
```

Comment: It's still not working.. Unfortunately I have no time to test it well now. I have also decided, in the meantime, to drop jetty and use a pure websocket based backend.